# Tensorflow InvalidArgumentError Matrix size incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I start the simple neural net I got an error. By the way, the code should output the first number of the test array.

There have been other errors(there was one having to do with the data's dtype).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

data = np.array([[0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
labels = np.array([0, 0, 1])
data.dtype = float
print(data.dtype)
model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.relu),
keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data, labels)
prediction = model.predict([0, 1, 0])
print(prediction)
```

I get this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [3,1], In[1]: [3,3]
     [[{{node sequential/dense/Relu}}]]
```

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by `the code should output the first number of the test array.`?

Comment: If it is [0, 0, 1]  it should output . 0

Comment: I don't understand. That's not what you will get as an output from your neural network. There is `2` in the second dense layer which means you will get 2 values as an output. Check the result yourself after modifying your above code as per my answer below.

Comment: BTW, each element in `[0, 0, 1]` is a label for different data feature. For above case, 0 for [0, 1, 1], 0 for [0, 0, 1] and 1 for [1, 1, 1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting above error because of below line:

```
prediction = model.predict([0, 1, 0])
```

You are passing a `list` which should be a numpy array and of shape `Nx3`, where `N` is basically batch size and can be 1, 2, etc. In this case, it will be `1`.

In order to make it correct, change it to

`prediction = model.predict(np.expand_dims(np.array([0, 1, 0], dtype=np.float32), 0))`

or

`prediction = model.predict(np.array([[0, 1, 0]], dtype=np.float32))`

And, change `data.dtype = float` to `data.dtype = np.float32`.

Comment: excuse  me can you help in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225332/matrix-size-incompatible?